# Apache on os x Mojave does not serve index.php

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, macos-mojave

I brewed Apache and PHP on a relatively new Mojave installation. In httpd.conf I specify "DirectoryIndex index.php index.html" When I enter 127.0.0.1 in the address line of Chrome I get the following error "This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". The content of my index.php is phpinfo(). When I change the order of DirectoyIndex to "DirectoryIndex index.html index.php" all works well and index.html is served. It actually seems like no php file is served at all. Any advice what may have gone wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `I try to send` and `I enter` , be very specific about what you do / how . Do you have a `index.php`, is php enabled on your server , etc...

Comment: Thank you @YvesLeBorg. I made my question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from PHP5.6 to PHP7.2 solved the problem.